Godot connect runtime error and Callable compiler error
I recently started using Godot and still learning. I joined a game jam for more learning experience and i have some errors with my code that is attached to a button that is supposed to load a separate scene in 12 specific parts. Some of the code uses what i think should be Callable or connect but it wont work with either.
I tried changing the spot of error from "connect" to "Callable" but it only adds a runtime error.Ill show the errors i get with connect and Callable. The bold line is the line where the error occurs.
connect:

Line 23:Invalid argument for "connect()" function: argument 2 should be "Callable" but is "res://scenes/spawn_button_1.gd".
Line 23:Cannot pass a value of type "String" as "int".
Line 23:Invalid argument for "connect()" function: argument 3 should be "int" but is "String".

Callable(this is the main error, I think this is supposed to be the word but the following error blocks me):

Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'Callable' in base 'Button(spawn_button_1.gd)'.

Here is my code:
extends Button

#var rares = {"common" : 15,
    #"rare" : 5,
    #"worthless" : 2}
            
@export var scene_to_spawn : PackedScene

@onready var spawn_button = $"."

var spawn_positions = [
    Vector2(-65, -65), Vector2(120, -65), Vector2(65, -28),
    Vector2(-25, -65), Vector2(160, -65), Vector2(15, -28),
    Vector2(15, -65), Vector2(160, -28), Vector2(-25, -28),
    Vector2(65, -65), Vector2(120, -28), Vector2(-65, -28)
]

var occupied_positions = []

func _ready() -> void:
     **spawn_button.Callable("pressed", "_on_Button_pressed")**

func _on_pressed() -> void:
    your text`var available_positions = get_available_positions()
    
    if available_positions.size() > 0:
        var random_position = available_positions[randi() % available_positions.size()]
    
        var new_scene = scene_to_spawn.instantiate()
    
    new_scene.position = random_position

    add_child(new_scene)
        
    occupied_positions.append(random_position)
else:
    print("no spots!")
        
func get_available_positions() -> Array:
    var available_positions = []
    
    for position in spawn_positions:
        if !occupied_positions.has(position):
            available_positions.append(position)
        return available_positions

If there is any more info needed just ask and I'll see if I have it.

i solved the issue. i had to add Callable after the first , and add self, inside the second set of parentheses                                                                                            spawn_button.connect("pressed", Callable(self, "_on_pressed"))

You can do it with less hardcoded strings.
func _ready():
  self.pressed.conect(_on_pressed)

See the _on_pressed is without parthesis. That means, the function will NOT be called, but it behaves like variaoble typed as Callable.
